# Upgrade repast simphony version 1.2 to repast 2.0

Tags: java, simulation, repast-simphony

I need your help. I'm running a repast simulation from another Java application.
What I intend to do is to upgrade the repast version 1.2 to the repast version 2.0.

How can I do this?

I tried to replace the repast.simphony.bin_and_src.jar with the latest version of it (repast 2.0) but such an error occurs:

```
repast.simphony.scenario.ScenarioLoadException: C:\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\...\score.rs\user_path.xml (The system cannot find the file specified)
at repast.simphony.scenario.ScenarioLoader.load(ScenarioLoader.java:219)
at lab.MyRunner.load(MyRunner.java:45)
at lab.MyExperiment.<init>(MyExperiment.java:39)
at servlets.SimServlet.doPost(SimServlet.java:126)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:861)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:606)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
at java.lang.Thread.run (Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\...\score.rs\user_path.xml (The system cannot find the file specified)
at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
at java.io.FileReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
at repast.simphony.scenario.data.UserPathFileReader.read(UserPathFileReader.java:43)
at repast.simphony.scenario.ScenarioLoader.load(ScenarioLoader.java:108)
```

Answer (score 1):

I saw your question as I have this problem too. I found the cause of the problem in 
[this email group.](http://repast.10935.n7.nabble.com/repast-model-that-ran-last-year-won-t-run-now-td8080.html) For those that aren't interested in clicking on a link, the problem arises because `user_path.xml` files were introduced with Repast Simphony 2.0, whereas earlier versions do not use this file.

There is apparently an automated method to update your old packages, see [section 2.5 here](http://repast.sourceforge.net/docs/RepastSimphonyFAQ.pdf). But there could still be issues with the code.

I'm going to try to reconstruct the program I'm trying to use in the latest version. As Nick says in his reply in that archive, the alternative is to install an earlier version of RS which doesn't have `user_path.xml` files.